# How dow I find all log files created between 4 and 7 o'clock this morning?

Tags: unix, find

I'm looking for a command which lists all files created between 4 and 7:40 o'clock this morning. I'm aware of `find . -mtime 0` but that lists all files created today. I can pipe it to a grep but than my knowledge fails me on how to filter out all files but the files created between 4 and 7:40.

Comment: A bunch of [file systems](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata) don't actually have a creation timestamp, including ext3 (ext4 has it). Are you really looking for modification timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU `find`, you can do this:

```
find -newermt "2011-03-17 04:00" ! -newermt "2011-03-17 07:40"
```

With other versions of `find`, you can do something like this:

```
touch -d "2011-03-17 04:00" start
touch -d "2011-03-17 07:40" end
find -newer start ! -newer end
rm start end
```

Comment: our unix versions uses -t instead of -d, and date version is slightly different: touch -t "201103170740" end. Apart from that this worked beautiful!
Oh and today is 18 mar in our timezone. Produced some unexpected results :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `-mmin` option of find uses minutes instead of days.